# How much RAM will my PHP application have access to on a 32bit server?

Tags: 10.04, server, php, memory

I have a 32bit 10.04 server has 32gb ram

I am running opencart e-commerce sites (php)

Max How much ram can use by opencart? (32gb or 4gb?)

Comment: Why not just run a 64bit kernel?  That will almost certainly be faster.

Comment: this is an existing server runs alot of sites.

Comment: isn't any RAM limit in 64bit?

Comment: In 64-bit the only limit is how much memory the hardware can accept.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [PAE-kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE) a 32 bit operating systems like yours, can use up to 64 Gb of memory (RAM).

Comment: mm, kinda, not from one process.

Comment: Every php code is a single process isn't it? Not whole opencart application. In this case, max limit is 64 gb, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PAE kernel installed, your 32 bit operating system should be able to address up to 64 GB of RAM.

As far as I know, each single process should be able to address not more than 4 GB RAM. Now since opencart is a PHP application and I assume that each visit of your website by another browser spwans a new PHP process, your system and therefore opencart should be able to use more than 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: +1 for the extra info (and to motivate each other :) )

Comment: Every php code is a single process isn't it? Not whole opencart application. In this case, max limit is 64 gb, am I right?

Comment: Yes, typically you'll have multiple php processes, and they can each get >3GB.  If no single request wants more than 3GB, you're fine.  I don't know if that's your situation or not.

Comment: @poolie 3gb or 4gb?

Comment: I don't think apps get the full 4GB with a 32-bit kernel.  Not sure exactly where the cutoff is these days.

Answer (score 0):

Also, PHP has various tuning parameters, including `memory_limit`, which may be as high as 128MiB if you're running a recent version.  Check your `php.ini` file for details.